# If I do Object a=b and then b.change() will a change as well?

Tags: java, variables, object

If I have

```
public class Bike{
    private int speed;

    public void setSpeed(int speed){
        this.speed=speed;
    }

   public int getSpeed(){
        return speed;
    }
```

then if I create `Bike a=new Bike();`
and I do

```
Bike b=a;
b.setSpeed(12);
```

Will the speed of bike `a` change as well?
If not is there any way to do that?

Comment: Why not just try it and see?

Comment: Bike a and bike b are the same bike. Not two bikes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will change. The Java Assignment operation just creates a new *reference* to the object. In other words writing something like

```
Object objectA = objectB
```

will **not** copy all values in the object. Both objectA and objectB point to the same *instance* of the class.

If you want to copy all values of an object you should take a look at [clone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the speed of bike `a` will change, because both object references `a` and `b` refer to the same object.

```
a ----> Bike object
        ^
       /
b -----
```

The only way for that not to be the case is to change one of the references to be another object.

```
b = new Bike();
```

Then you could visualize it this way:

```
a ----> Bike object

b -----> Another Bike object
```

Answer (score 0):

After that statement `Bike b = a;`, `a` and `b` refer to the **same object**. Any changes to `a`  will be reflected in `b`, and vice versa. This is because both variables are references to an object.

```
Bike a = new Bike(10);
Bike b = a;
a.changeSpeed(20); // This affects both a AND b
```

After the statement `int x = y;`, changes to `x` will not be reflected in `y`. This is because x and y are primitive variables, not object references.

```
int x = 5;
int y = x;
x = 10; // This affects x only
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's references. And you can check it really easy -- it would even required less time then asking question here.